# How to connect a 4x4 matrix keypad to one analog pin?

Tags: voltage-divider, arduino-uno, circuits, keypad

I watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eku28glwHYo) on YouTube, the video's creator shows how we can connect a keypad to just one single analog pin of Arduino UNO instead of using (number of columns + number of rows) pins by using voltage divider method. The complete circuit is: [image]

I am asking if anyone can explain how the voltage divider circuit at the most right of the image works. I know voltage divider is when you measure voltage at a node between two resistors, for example: if we have 2 series resistors each has a resistance R, one of the two terminals is connected to VCC and the other is connected to GND. Then, the voltage at the node between them is R*VCC/2R = 0.5*VCC.

I do not know how I can apply the same rule here.

Also, by referring to this [tutorial](https://lastminuteengineers.com/arduino-keypad-tutorial/), I know how the keypad works in the normal connection, the rows pins are pulled high, then a column is pulled down, and checks if one of the rows is 0 instead of 1, this is repeated for each column and this process determines which key is pressed.

Comment: draw a schematic diagram for four keys only ... draw one for 1, 5 ,9, D ... draw another for 1, 2, 3, A ... and another for 1, 4, 7 ,* ... examine the three diagrams

Answer (score 1):

The circuit and resistors are made so that pushing one button selects two resistances to pull down for that row and column, and there is a single pull up resistor.

Therefore pushing each of the 16 different buttons will generate 16 different voltage levels, and 17th level means no button is pushed.

Answer (score 0):

I simulated an analog keypad for a 3x4 matrix:

[image: Analog keypad 3x4]